# JWT Authentication using a custom attribute in .NET Core Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm currently converting my Web API 2.0 to .NET Core Web API but there is one section I'm struggling with.

In my existing API, I have an attribute with the following code:

```
public class JwtAuthentication : Attribute, IAuthenticationFilter
{
    public string Realm { get; set; }

    public bool AllowMultiple => false;

    public async Task AuthenticateAsync(
        HttpAuthenticationContext context, 
        CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var request = context.Request;

        var authorization = request.Headers.Authorization;

        // checking request header value having required scheme "Bearer" or not.
        if (authorization == null ||
            authorization.Scheme.ToLowerInvariant() != "bearer" ||
            string.IsNullOrEmpty(authorization.Parameter))
        {
            context.ErrorResult = new AuthenticationFailureResult("JWT Token is Missing", request);
            return;
        }

        // Getting Token value from header values.
        var token = authorization.Parameter;
        var principal = await AuthJwtToken(token);

        if (principal == null)
        {
            context.ErrorResult = new AuthenticationFailureResult("Invalid JWT Token", request);
        }
        else
        {
            context.Principal = principal;
        }
    }

    private static bool ValidateToken(string token, out ICollection<Claim> claims)
    {
        claims = null;

        var simplePrinciple = JwtAuthManager.GetPrincipal(token);

        if (simplePrinciple == null)
        {
            return false;
        }

        var identity = simplePrinciple.Identity as ClaimsIdentity;

        if (identity == null)
        {
            return false;
        }

        if (!identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            return false;
        }

        var usernameClaim = identity.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.Name);
        var emailClaim = identity.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.Email);

        var username = usernameClaim?.Value;
        var email = emailClaim?.Value;

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(username) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(email))
        {
            return false;
        }

        claims = identity.Claims.ToList();

        return true;
    }

    protected Task<IPrincipal> AuthJwtToken(string token)
    {
        if (ValidateToken(token, out var claims))
        {
            var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, "Jwt");

            IPrincipal user = new ClaimsPrincipal(identity);

            return Task.FromResult(user);
        }

        return Task.FromResult<IPrincipal>(null);
    }

    public Task ChallengeAsync(
        HttpAuthenticationChallengeContext context, 
        CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        Challenge(context);
        return Task.FromResult(0);
    }

    private void Challenge(HttpAuthenticationChallengeContext context)
    {
        string parameter = null;

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Realm))
        {
            parameter = "realm=\"" + Realm + "\"";
        }

        context.ChallengeWith("Bearer", parameter);
    }
}
```

If I understand correctly, in ASP.NET Core, all I have to do is define the following in my startup:

```
services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddJwtBearer(options =>  
    {  
        options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters  
        {  
            ValidateIssuer = true,  
            ValidateAudience = true,  
            ValidateLifetime = true,  
            ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,  
            ValidIssuer = Configuration["Jwt:Issuer"],  
            ValidAudience = Configuration["Jwt:Issuer"],  
            IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Configuration["Jwt:Key"]))  
        };  
    });
```

and I'm not sure whether or not I'll need the below but it looks like it:

```
services.AddMvc();
```

and all I could do is use the [Authorize] attribute but what if I want to replicate the Attribute I used in my ASP.NET MVC Web API 2.0?

Should I? I like the fact that I can see where things have gone wrong with the token. If it can be used the same way and assuming it is OK to do so, how do I do this? I haven't found anything that would help when googling for a solution?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you don't want to reinvent the whole bearer token authentication wheel.

In case you'd like to customize how events are handled you can use [JwtBearerOptions.Events Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.authentication.jwtbearer.jwtbeareroptions.events?view=aspnetcore-2.2#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Authentication_JwtBearer_JwtBearerOptions_Events) to hook your own delegates to one or more of them. ([OnAuthenticationFailed Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.authentication.jwtbearer.jwtbearerevents.onauthenticationfailed?view=aspnetcore-2.2#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Authentication_JwtBearer_JwtBearerEvents_OnAuthenticationFailed), [OnChallenge Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.authentication.jwtbearer.jwtbearerevents.onchallenge?view=aspnetcore-2.2#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Authentication_JwtBearer_JwtBearerEvents_OnChallenge), [OnMessageReceived  Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.authentication.jwtbearer.jwtbearerevents.onmessagereceived?view=aspnetcore-2.2), [OnTokenValidated Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.authentication.jwtbearer.jwtbearerevents.ontokenvalidated?view=aspnetcore-2.2)).

Example failed authentication logging.

```
services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddJwtBearer(options =>  
    {  
        options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters  
        {  
            ValidateIssuer = true,  
            ValidateAudience = true,  
            ValidateLifetime = true,  
            ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,  
            ValidIssuer = Configuration["Jwt:Issuer"],  
            ValidAudience = Configuration["Jwt:Issuer"],  
            IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Configuration["Jwt:Key"]))  
        };

    options.Events.OnAuthenticationFailed = (context) =>
    {
        // Log failed authentication here

        // Return control back to JWT Bearer middleware
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
});
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Apologies for the delay. The events is exactly what I was looking for. I'll check the rest of them in a sec, but that's definitely a good start. Thanks again.

Comment: Actually I spoke to quickly. I'm getting an error `System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'` and upon reading it further on the Microsoft website, it appears to only be compatible up to .net core 2.2 unless their documentation is out of date. Will update later.

Answer (score 1):

Based on @dropoutcoder answer,

As `Events` in `options.Events` is null, I was getting an error `object reference not set...` and to get around this problem I used the following instead:

```
options.Events = new JwtBearerEvents()
{
    OnMessageReceived = context =>
    {
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    },
    OnAuthenticationFailed = context =>
    {
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    },
    OnTokenValidated = context =>
    {
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    },
    OnChallenge = context =>
    {
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    },
    OnForbidden = context =>
    {
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
};
```